# Basic bash script returns "invalid syntax"

Tags: bash

Can't explain why this is happening.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Here's the terminal output:

```
$ python ./test.sh 
    File "./tellapart_mac_setup.sh", line 2
        echo "Hello World"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ echo "hello world"
hello world

$ which bash
/bin/bash

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you're parsing it with python, since it's not a python script - it of course will throw errors in python's compiler.

It's a bash script, so just use bash to process it:

```
./test.sh
```