# How to test DB connection Using Google Cloud SQL, Secrets Manager with Django 4.1 gcloud setup. Windows 10

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-secret-manager

I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#console_5) and when I get to "python manage.py make mirations" I get the error -  Models aren't loaded yet

cloud-sql-proxy.exe is running on another cmd.
I am trying to troubleshoot this but I am very new to Google Cloud SQL and Secrets Manager.  Is there a way to determine if the issue is the secrets manager, the code or the DB?

**See this ACCEPTED answer** [Reading django_settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687306/reading-django-settings-from-google-cloud-platforms-secret-manager-does-not-wor)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\manage.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\manage.py", line 32, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 18, in check_all_models
    models = apps.get_models()
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 181, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "D:\Programming\Django\Polls\pollenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 143, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

My settings.py

```
import io
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import environ
import google.auth
from google.cloud import secretmanager

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# [START cloudrun_django_secret_config]
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# Change this to "False" when you are ready for production
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, True))
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

# Attempt to load the Project ID into the environment, safely failing on error.
try:
    _, os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = google.auth.default()
except google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
    pass

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided

    env.read_env(env_file)
# [START_EXCLUDE]
elif os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    # Create local settings if running with CI, for unit testing

    placeholder = (
        f"SECRET_KEY=a\n"
        "GS_BUCKET_NAME=None\n"
        f"DATABASE_URL=sqlite://{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')}"
    )
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(placeholder))
# [END_EXCLUDE]
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
# [END cloudrun_django_secret_config]
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = env("DEBUG")

# [START cloudrun_django_csrf]
# SECURITY WARNING: It's recommended that you use this when
# running in production. The URL will be known once you first deploy
# to Cloud Run. This code takes the URL and converts it to both these settings formats.
CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL = env("CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL", default=None)
if CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL).netloc]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL]
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
# [END cloudrun_django_csrf]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "polls.apps.PollsConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mysite",
    "storages",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "mysite.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.wsgi.application"

# Database
# [START cloudrun_django_database_config]
# Use django-environ to parse the connection string
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432

# [END cloudrun_django_database_config]

# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# [START cloudrun_django_static_config]
# Define static storage via django-storages[google]
GS_BUCKET_NAME = env("GS_BUCKET_NAME")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "publicRead"
# [END cloudrun_django_static_config]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

Comment: Do you have your app in registered `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: The code was from the tutorial GIT - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/run/django

Comment: Try to run only `python manage.py`, it might reveal the cause

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from "apply migrations": KeyError: "(cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1)"

Comment: After manage.py - Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Set the (cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) environment variable).

Comment: The post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687306/reading-django-settings-from-google-cloud-platforms-secret-manager-does-not-wor  accepted answer worked.

Comment: @CaryH, please post your previous comment as an answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions.

Comment: I will shortly.  I am having issues with the bucket now and assume it is similar.  When that is fixed,  I'll post full answer.